# Decode JSON with jQuery / AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, decode

I'm trying to decode a JSON with jQuery. 
Here's what I get (for instance a class, here with one student):

```
"{"Students":[{"Name":John,"Grade":17,}],"TotalClass":17,"TotalCount":1,}"
```

here's what I do:

```
$j.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'class.aspx/getClass',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (msg) {
        $j.each(msg, function (index, element) {
            alert(element.TotalClass);
        });
    },
});
```

It keeps saying undefined in the alert (but I recieve the right JSON). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is that the actual json as returned by the server? Also, you have an extra comma on the second to last line.

Comment: If you receive the quotes you've put around the json, that can't be parsed.

Comment: Is that the *exact* JSON the server returns?  Because it's invalid.

Comment: @dystroy  I was under the impression that you can parse JSON with quotes, you just have to call 
JSON.parse(stringified_version);

Comment: I had a similar problem - the JSON response was not ,,translated'' to JS object. The reason was quite simple: I wrote `datatype` instead of `dataType`... So it's worthy to check such things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{"Students":[{"Name":John,"Grade":17,}],"TotalClass":17,"TotalCount":1,}
```

**is not valid JSON !**

Assuming you have a valid `JSON` like this

```
{
    "Students": [
        {
            "Name": "John",
            "Grade": "17"
        }
    ],
    "TotalClass": " 17",
    "TotalCount": "1"
}
```

You can access the values like this

```
alert("TotalClass : "+msg.TotalClass);
//loop thru students
$.each(msg.Students,function(index,item){
   alert(item.Name+ " - "+item.Grade)
});
```

Working sample :  http://jsfiddle.net/ncbLF/5/

Use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate JSON

So your code can be simplified to

```
$.getJSON("class.aspx/getClass",function(msg){

    alert("TotalClass : "+msg.TotalClass);
    $.each(msg.Students,function(index,item){
        alert(item.Name+ " - "+item.Grade)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try to alert

```
$j.each(msg, function (key, element) {
    alert(key); // output: Students, TotalClass..
    alert(element); //output: [{"Name":John,"Grade":17,}, 17..
});
```

#### Note

as you set `dataType: 'json'` so I think you don't need any additional parse effort and given JSON has error, don't know is it your written or originally sent from server.

And you don't need the line

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

You valid json should look like:

```
{
    "Students": [
        {
            "Name": "John",
            "Grade": "17"
        }
    ],
    "TotalClass": " 17",
    "TotalCount": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`contentType` is the type of the data sent *to* the server, not from.  Remove that.

The JSON you included in the question.  Is that the *exact* JSON the server returns?  Because if it is, you don't need the `$.each`.  You have an object, you should only need `$.each` to loop though an array of objects.

So, just try `alert(msg.TotalClass)`.

Also, that JSON is invalid.  You have an extra `,` after `TotalCount`, and after `Grade`.  Also, `John` should be in double quotes.