# JSON return not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

im just doing a simple login script but via ajax.

I have used the same script for the javascript side of things elsewhere and it has been fine, but this doesnt seem to work for what im trying now.

So, i am using this for the return:

```
    $return['loginSuccess'] = true;
    echo json_encode($return);
```

And then to catch the return this:

```
    if (response.loginSuccess === true) {
        window.location = "index.php";
    } else {
        // error
    }
```

However, nothing happens when the return is sent. I have removed the javascript side, and the login.php page shows that it is sending the response of loginSuccess = True.

Cant see why its working on other scripts but nothing is happening for this.

Here is full javascript (i have removed the validation to keep it shorter):

```
// JavaScript - Login AJAX

$(document).ready(function(){

// When the form is submitted
$('.loginbutton').click(function(){

    var check = true;

    // Get the values
    var usernamelogin = $('.logininputuser').val();
    var passwordlogin = $('.logininputpass').val();

    // Database validation checks
    if (check === true) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "process/login.php",
    data: $(".formlogin").serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response){

    if (response.loginSuccess === true) {
        window.location = "index.php";
    } else {
        // error
    }

    }
    });
}
        return false;
    });
});
```

And the php:

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json');
require("../common.php"); 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

if(!empty($_POST['loginbutton'])) { 
    $query = " SELECT id, username, password, salt, email FROM users WHERE username = :username "; 

    // Create bound values
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
    ); 

    try 
    { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex) 
    { 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
    } 

    $login_ok = false; 

    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row) 
    { 

        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
        } 

        if($check_password === $row['password']) 
        { 
            $login_ok = true; 
        } 
    } 

    // Sucsess for login
    if($login_ok) 
    { 
        unset($row['salt']); 
        unset($row['password']); 
        $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['logged'] = "1";
        $return['loginSuccess'] = true;
        echo json_encode($return);                
    } 
    else 
    { 
        die();
    }

    } else if(!empty($_POST['regbutton'])) {

        header( 'Location: ../register.php' ) ;
    }
}

 ?>
```

Sorry for the lengthy question, not sure if its possible to see whats wrong with this code or not but thanks for any help if you can.

Comment: Check by adding logs on success response and also add an error callback for ajax, then try to debug it.

Comment: what message do you have on your debugger when you `console.log(response)` in you ajax return ?

Comment: btw what does return  `var_dump($_POST['username'])` ?

Comment: I am getting no messages in my debugger :/

Seems its not getting the return correctly then?
 All works fine without the javascript side of things though.

Comment: inspect the actual request in network tab of console...can see exactly what is sent , returned, status etc. Need to at least narrow down if problem is client or server side and inspecting request should give you plenty of clues

Comment: Sorted it now, for some reason this part: if(!empty($_POST['loginbutton'])) { } was causing it not to work. Cant explain why but... thanks for the help, learnt about the console.log as well which will defo come in use in future!

Answer (score -1):

I think you haven't decode the json encoded string so it not worlking.
Try This Code.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" )
```

where  '{ "name": "John" }' is your response.

For more reference, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ OR [Decode JSON with jQuery / AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018527/decode-json-with-jquery-ajax)